# Retail Huff Model & Network Analyst - Street/Travel Time Network error/issue/question

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, modelling

I am writing in regards to the [Huff Model](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f4769668fc3f486a992955ce55caca18) that Drew Flater posted on ESRI's website since I seem to be running into a problem whenever I try to run it with a network. I've tried emailing/contacting the author, but no luck.

**The model is not generating outputs for all of my supply points, including my planned store location whenever I run the model with a network I've created.** I've followed ESRI's tutorial on creating multi-modal/pedestrian networks.

I've got 172 supply points (cafes) + 1 (my potential site), but when I run the Huff Model toolbox the analysis only gives me outputs for 69 supply points? Why am I not getting outputs (probability & sales) for all 173 supply points? Screenshots are below.

The model runs fine whenever I do not include a network, but I need the Huff Model to account for travel time/multi-modal transportation networks...the example below is meant to account for solely walking since I'm modeling walking distances to and from local coffee shops.

Please note I have 141 Demand Points (polygons, neighborhoods) and 173 supply points in total:

NETWORK:

[image]

[image]

[image]

SUPPLY POINTS OUTPUTS AFTER RUNNING HUFF MODEL TOOL:

[image]

[image]

MAP & SUPPLY POINTS FULL LIST:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are other differences between your failing and succeding supply points? Are the missing ones maybe not fetching to your road-network?

Comment: I think it had to do with the cafes/supply points not being snapped/connected to a road! This is a bit old, but thanks for asking!